# HTML5 contentEditable check if format is applied with execCommand?

Tags: javascript, html, contenteditable, execcommand

Making the selected text bold:

```
document.execCommand('bold', null, null);
```

When the user selects that piece of text again (or a part of it), how can you know that it has been made bold?

Bold is just an example. The `commandName` could be `underline`, `heading`, `createLink`, ...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> ```
> document.queryCommandState
> ```
>
> Determines whether the given command has been executed on the current
>   selection.

Source: http://blog.whatwg.org/the-road-to-html-5-contenteditable#how

Apparently I didn't search well enough.

Answer (score 0):

You'll know it's bold because it's been wrapped with `<b></b>` tags. (or whatever the user-agent uses for bolding text)

Comment: So there are no helper methods here? You need to parse everything yourself?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of, but I could be mistaken. Use getSelection() to get the selected node(s) and then check style.fontWeight to see if it's bold. repeat for everything you want to test.

Comment: @evan: There is a built-in method, which @DADU found.